# Conduction modeling

Tags: physics

This might seem like a simple question, but I cannot for the life of me find a solution through google.
**How long would it take for a hot metal block to reach room temperature?**
Google only shows examples for water in a container, which is an example of convection. I'm pretty sure this is conduction but I can't say im certain.
Lets say the metal is iron (arbitrary, i'm looking to solve this analytically)

Comment: Are you familiar with the [heat equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation)?

Comment: The temperature difference between the block and the room approaches zero exponentially never actually getting there.

Comment: I am familiar with the heat equation. However, I do not have a function to describe how temperature changes across a spatial gradient or how it changes with respect to time.

Comment: An interesting article [here](http://users.df.uba.ar/sgil/physics_paper_doc/papers_phys/termo/kitchen_cool.pdf) which might be useful.